# Laravel repository pattern add query

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I am making a repository pattern in Laravel, and I have made an `AbstractRepository` class which is extended by any repository to get the most used CRUD methods which can be shared.

Now I can extend the main functionality by adding additional methods to concrete repositories if I need some more complex queries.

For example:

```
public function eagerWhere($column, $value, $relation, $orderBy = 'name')
{
    return Region::with($relation)->where($column, $value)->orderBy($orderBy);
}
```

Now the part I'm having trouble with is this part in the main code which uses my repository:

```
$regions = $this->regionRepository->eagerWhere('name', $term, 'country');


if ($includeCountry) { //<-- from here
    $regions->orWhereHas('country', function ($query) use ($term) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
    });
}
```

How can I write that part in the repository so that ultimately I can make it look like:

```
$regions = $this->regionRepository->eagerWhere('name', $term, 'country');


if ($includeCountry) {
    $regions->orWhereHas($term, 'country');
}
```

I tried copying that part of the code to repository, but then I can't chain methods because when `$region` is fetched, it is no longer considered to be a repository instance, but `Eloquent` one. And now it is expecting `Eloquent` method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to do *quite* what I wanted, but the fix that was satisfying solution was to put the complete logic inside the method, so now I have this:

```
public function eagerWhereLike($column, $value, $relation, $searchOnRelation = false, $orderBy = 'name')
{
    $regions = Region::with($relation)->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')->orderBy($orderBy);

    if ($searchOnRelation) {
        $regions->orWhereHas($relation, function ($query) use ($column, $value) {
            $query->where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
        });
    }

    return $regions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your level of abstractation its a bit mixed, since you are not abstracting the model itself also, but anyways. A solution might be like this :

```
public function eagerWhere($column, $value, $relation)
{
    $builder = Region::with($relation)->where($column, $value);

    return $builder
}
```

then:

```
$regions = $this->regionRepository->eagerWhere('name', $term, 'country');


if ($includeCountry) {

    $regions->orWhereHas($term, 'country');
}

return $regions->orderBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: What do you mean by my level of abstraction being mixed? `eagerWhere()` is a method in `RegionRepository`, not `AbstractRepository`. Isn't that ok?

Comment: I mean, I can go with query builder and use `DB` facade, but isn't that the same dependency then as `Eloquent` would be?

Comment: then thats fine, I thought Region was in `AbstractRepository`  !

Comment: well both `DB` and `Eloquent` they yield a builder instance, the difference is that `Eloquent` has properties which set up `builder` with predefined params. while `DB` not.

Comment: I know, but for simplicity, if I don't need special optimizations and speed, `Eloquent` will serve its purpose and maintain the repository pattern, right?

Comment: Nope, it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($conditions['search']) && !empty($conditions['search'])) {
        $search = strtolower($conditions['search']);

        $maintanceTechnician->orWhereRaw(
            "LOWER(CONCAT(IFNULL(first_name,''),' ',IFNULL(last_name,''),' ',IFNULL(mobile_no,''))) like ?",
            ["%{$search}%"]
        );

        if (isset($conditions['post_code']) && !empty($conditions['post_code'])) {
            $maintanceTechnician->orWhere('post_code', trim($conditions['post_code']));
        }

    }
```